# Local Web API 2 Authorize not working with Azure identity token

Tags: azure-active-directory, asp.net-web-api2, single-sign-on

I have a project that is using SSO and is returning access and identity tokens from Azure AD.  I get the tokens back just fine upon redirect, as well as the role assignments for the login but when attempting to access API endpoints I get HTTP 401 on my local machine but it works just fine on the test server.

I have the [Authorize] prefix for my endpoints and I've tried hitting endpoints with and without the role assignments.  I'm using web config transforms and I've double checked the URLs for the allowed origin to make sure that they're correct.

This just makes it really difficult when trying to debug as I have to push the frontend or backend to the test server instead of being able to work on my local machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being something in my web.config that was denying the Authorize tag from working.  I ended up starting with a base web.config and readding options that I needed and after doing so the calls were working as expected.  Moral of the story, check your web.config if you run into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You would be getting an 403 forbidden status code if it was a role issue.

Ensure the access token retrieved locally [aud claim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#payload-claims) matches the [API uri id](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad#-create-an-app-registration-in-azure-ad-for-your-app-service-app), which usually follows the format `api://{app id}`. If that's not the case then locally you're targeting a different API.

Comment: Yep.  I double checked and they do match.